# Error when optimizing C++ code with inline assembly

Tags: c++, g++, inline-assembly, clang++

I am trying to learn inline assembly and I implemented Euclid algorithm in assembly! Now when I am trying to run my code with

```
g++ filename -O1
```

it's compiling and running fine but when I am trying to do the same with

```
clang++-3.6 filename -O1
```

code is compiling but producing segmentation fault!

Also both `gcc` and `clang` producing compile time error when I am trying to run my code with `-O2` or higher flags!

**g++ error**

```
eculid.cpp: Assembler messages:
eculid.cpp:19: Error: symbol `CONTD' is already defined
eculid.cpp:19: Error: symbol `DONE' is already defined
```

**clang error**

```
eculid.cpp:7:5: error: invalid symbol redefinition
                            "movl %1, %%eax;"
                            ^
<inline asm>:1:34: note: instantiated into assembly here
    movl %eax, %eax;movl %ecx, %ebx;CONTD: cmpl $0, %ebx;je DONE;xor...
                                    ^
eculid.cpp:7:5: error: invalid symbol redefinition
                            "movl %1, %%eax;"
                            ^
<inline asm>:1:132: note: instantiated into assembly here
  ...%edx;idivl %ebx;movl %ebx, %eax;movl %edx, %ebx;jmp CONTD;DONE: movl %ea...
                                                           ^
2 errors generated.
```

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int gcd(int var1, int var2) {
    int result = 0;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "movl %1, %%eax;"
            "movl %2, %%ebx;"
            "CONTD: cmpl $0, %%ebx;"
            "je DONE;"
            "xorl %%edx, %%edx;"
            "idivl %%ebx;"
            "movl %%ebx, %%eax;"
            "movl %%edx, %%ebx;"
            "jmp CONTD;"
            "DONE: movl %%eax, %0;"
            :"=r"(result)
            :"r"(var1), "r"(var2)
        );
    return result;
}

int main(void) {

    int first = 0, second = 0;
    cin >> first >> second;
    cout << "GCD is: " << gcd(first, second) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can check my code [here](http://ideone.com/KIucxZ) (same error produced by my compiler)

[image]

Comment: You have a couple of problems. You are changing the contents of registers without letting gcc know, and you aren't using unique names for your labels.  While I haven't run this, how about something more like (sorry about the formatting): `__asm__ ("cmpl $0, %%ebx\n\t" "je DONE%=\n\t" "CONTD%=:\n\t" "xorl %%edx, %%edx\n\t" "idivl %%ebx\n\t" "movl %%ebx, %%eax\n\t" "movl %%edx, %%ebx\n\t" "cmpl $0, %%ebx\n\t" "jne CONTD%=\n" "DONE%=:" :"=a"(result), "+a"(var1), "+b"(var2) : /* no inputs */ : "edx");`. Details for gcc's inline asm are [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: Okay so just changing label with unique names (by **prefixing `%=`**) and adding **list of clobbered registers** now my code even working with -Ofast and -O3. Thanks for your help and yes that article is really nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put this in answer form so the question can be closed (please click the check mark next to this answer if it answers your question), at its simplest, you need to change your code like this:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movl %1, %%eax;"
        "movl %2, %%ebx;"
        "CONTD%=: cmpl $0, %%ebx;"
        "je DONE%=;"
        "xorl %%edx, %%edx;"
        "idivl %%ebx;"
        "movl %%ebx, %%eax;"
        "movl %%edx, %%ebx;"
        "jmp CONTD%=;"
        "DONE%=: movl %%eax, %0;"
        :"=r"(result)
        :"r"(var1), "r"(var2)
        : "eax", "ebx", "edx", "cc"
    );
```

Using %= adds a unique number to the identifiers to avoid conflicts.  And since the contents of registers and flags are being modified, you need to inform the compiler of that fact by 'clobbering' them.

But there are other things you can do that make this a bit faster, and a bit cleaner.  For example, instead of doing `movl %%eax, %0` at the end, you can just tell gcc that `result` will be in eax when the block exits:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movl %1, %%eax;"
        "movl %2, %%ebx;"
        "CONTD%=: cmpl $0, %%ebx;"
        "je DONE%=;"
        "xorl %%edx, %%edx;"
        "idivl %%ebx;"
        "movl %%ebx, %%eax;"
        "movl %%edx, %%ebx;"
        "jmp CONTD%=;"
        "DONE%=:"
        :"=a"(result)
        :"r"(var1), "r"(var2)
        : "ebx", "edx", "cc"
    );
```

Likewise, you can tell gcc to put var1 and var2 into eax and ebx for you before calling the block instead of you doing it manually inside the block:

```
__asm__ (
        "CONTD%=: cmpl $0, %%ebx;"
        "je DONE%=;"
        "xorl %%edx, %%edx;"
        "idivl %%ebx;"
        "movl %%ebx, %%eax;"
        "movl %%edx, %%ebx;"
        "jmp CONTD%=;"
        "DONE%=:"
        :"=a"(result), "+b"(var2)
        : "a"(var1)
        : "edx", "cc"
    );
```

Also, since you will (presumably) always be using result when calling gcd, volatile is unnecessary.  If you won't be using result, then there's no point forcing the calculation to be done anyway.

As written, the -S output for this statement will be one very long line, making debugging difficult.  That brings us to:

```
__asm__ (
   "CONTD%=:              \n\t"
      "cmpl $0, %%ebx     \n\t"
      "je DONE%=          \n\t"
      "xorl %%edx, %%edx  \n\t"
      "idivl %%ebx        \n\t"
      "movl %%ebx, %%eax  \n\t"
      "movl %%edx, %%ebx  \n\t"
      "jmp CONTD%=        \n"
   "DONE%=:"
   : "=a"(result), "+b"(var2)
   : "a"(var1)
   : "edx", "cc"
);
```

And I see no particular reason to force gcc to use ebx.  If we let gcc pick its own register (usually gives best performance), that gives us:

```
__asm__ (
   "CONTD%=:              \n\t"
      "cmpl $0, %1        \n\t"
      "je DONE%=          \n\t"
      "xorl %%edx, %%edx  \n\t"
      "idivl %1           \n\t"
      "movl %1, %%eax     \n\t"
      "movl %%edx, %1     \n\t"
      "jmp CONTD%=        \n"
   "DONE%=:"
   : "=a"(result), "+r"(var2)
   : "a"(var1)
   : "edx", "cc"
);
```

And lastly, avoiding the extra jump when the loop is complete gives us:

```
__asm__ (
      "cmpl $0, %1        \n\t"
      "je DONE%=          \n"
   "CONTD%=:              \n\t"
      "xorl %%edx, %%edx  \n\t"
      "idivl %1           \n\t"
      "movl %1, %%eax     \n\t"
      "movl %%edx, %1     \n\t"
      "cmpl $0, %1        \n\t"
      "jne CONTD%=        \n"
   "DONE%=:"
   : "=a"(result), "+r"(var2)
   : "a"(var1)
   : "edx", "cc"
);
```

Looking at the -S output from gcc, this gives us:

```
   /APP
        cmpl $0, %ecx
        je DONE31
   CONTD31:
        xorl %edx, %edx
        idivl %ecx
        movl %ecx, %eax
        movl %edx, %ecx
        cmpl $0, %ecx
        jne CONTD31
   DONE31:
   /NO_APP
```

This code uses fewer registers, performs fewer jumps and has fewer asm instructions than the original code.  FWIW.

For details about %=, clobbers, etc, check out the official [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for inline asm.

I suppose I should ask why you feel the need to write this in asm rather than just doing it in c, but I'll just assume you have a good reason.

Comment: Just what I wanted! :) +1 for your detailed answer

Comment: No special purpose for using inline asm but I suppose if I have time then why not learn it! after all it won't heart me if I know assembly and Now I know how to optimize inline assembly! :)